# Waiting for element to appear on static button in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, ui-testing

I have a strange behavior of TestCafe on my site. I have two checkboxes on a site and a button that brings me to the next step as soon as I click on it. When the page load, de button is visible and does not get manipulated at any time.

Here is the markup of the button:

```
<button id="confirmation-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right hidden-xs">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>
     order now
</button>
```

Here is what my code looks like (the relevant part for this problem):

```
const submitOrderBtn = Selector('button[type="submit"].btn-success');
//const submitOrderBtn = Selector('#confirmation-submit');

test('complete order', async t =>{
     await t
          .click(submitOrderBtn)
```

In chrome it shows me this picture:

[image]

The output of the command line is this:
[image]

The button is visible the whole time and even when I look over the site with the developer tools, the button is there and it has the id (confirmation-submit) that I want to be clicked.

How can I get around this problem? On other pages, I can use the .click function without any problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to say something without the full page source code. If you concern about privacy, you can send a link/source through private messages on our forum: https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/ to [me](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/users/AndreyBelym), [Helen Dikareva](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/users/helen-dikareva) or [Alexander Moskovkin](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/users/amoskovkin).

If you can't share your code, could you please try to write minimal reproducible example, please?

Comment: TestCafe will consider element visibile if its width or height have a non-zero value and it is not hided using CSS properties like `display: hidden` and `visibility: none`. You can check it in Computed CSS Properties in DevTools. In your case `#confirmation-button` might be an invisible button hidden somewhere in an actual visible element.

Also, you can try to resize browser window using [resizeWindow](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/resize-window.html) action. It may help if your layout is adaptive or it is a scrolling issue.

Answer (score 1):

As @Andrey Belym mentioned in his comment, TestCafe will consider element visibile if its width or height have a non-zero value and it is not hided using CSS properties like `display: hidden` and `visibility: none`.

You can check it in Computed CSS Properties in DevTools. In your case, `#confirmation-button` might be an invisible button hidden somewhere in an actual visible element.

Also, you can try to resize browser window using [resizeWindow](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/resize-window.html) action. It may help if your layout is adaptive or it is a scrolling issue.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could try to click on the button parent container:

```
const submitOrderBtn = Selector('#confirmation-submit');
const confirmSelector = submitOrderBtn.parent();
test('complete order', async t =>{
     await t
          .click(confirmSelector)
```

if this does not work for the immediate parent, you could try to fetch the first parent `div` like this:

```
const submitOrderBtn = Selector('#confirmation-submit');
    const confirmSelector = submitOrderBtn.parent('div');
    test('complete order', async t =>{
         await t
              .click(confirmSelector)
```

Answer (score 0):

<button *data-se-id="confirmation-submit"* type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right hidden-xs">

order now
</button

**and in test add like this : for click specified element :**

const submitOrderBtn =Selector('[data-se-id="confirmation-submit"]')
test('complete order', async t =>{
await t
.click(submitOrderBtn)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).